# Core Data inheritance: Is it OK to do this?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios

Example: I have an Entity called `Car` which is *abstract*. Then there are two child entities `Cabriolet` and `Pickup`.

Now I have an Entity called `Driver` which has a Relationship called `currentCar` 1..1 to the Entity `Car`. So I can assign either a Cabriolet or a Pickup to any driver's currentCar property. Then I would need to introspect the object to find out at runtime if I have a Cabriolet or Pickup when I get the currentCar from the driver. Is this a valid design in Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why this wouldn't work on a technical level, but it does violates OOP polymorphism.

Why do you need to know if the type of car? Would you be able to define the methods on the abstract superclass (`Car`) and override them as appropriate in the the subclasses (`Cabriolet` and `Pickup`)? Could you refactor the car hierarchy so that the attributes of the subclasses become more general and move them to attributes of `Car`, thus removing the need for the subclasses?

I had trouble with `NSFetchResultsController` when fetching objects derived from a common superclass. (The returned objects can only be sorted/grouped by an attribute of the entity. The class type is not an attribute so cannot be used to sort/group the entities. My solution/hack was to a `type` attribute to the superclass - ugly, but it worked.)

Comment: A Cabriolet adds an BOOL hasElectricRoof. Basically the question is if I fetch the currentCar, and I previously assigned a Cabriolet (which is a Car, too), then would I be able to cast it into a Cabriolet? Or is Core Data not going to fetch the properties that are defined in Cabriolet only?

Comment: @BugAlert: Yes. You can always fetch data with the `valueForKey:` method providing the class is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: That's not the point, Benedict. I know I can fetch objects. The point is: Will the specialized properties be available and fetched when the fault is fired, or will they not?!

Comment: The specialist selectors are simply methods which will call `valueForKey:`. It's perfectly possible for one `NSManagedObject` subclass to represent many disparate entities; there's no mechanism to check if the accessors declared in the subclass will match the entity it represents.