# Core Data parent Entity

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an abstract Entity A, I also have two Entities whom's parent is Entity A.
Each child has different relationships to other Entities.

I am trying to fetch all child Entities of Entity A, who's isPublic boolean value is YES.

I've had trouble with fetching subclassed Entities in the past in relation to fetching, and I'm sure I'm just not doing it correctly.

So we could say for example that :
• Entity A is "Document", 
• Entity B is "Poem",
• Entity C is "Article"

All poems and articles subclass document, and document has a property called isBookmarked, the suer can bookmark a poem or article, and I need a way of fetching all documents that are bookmarked. Entities B and C need to be independent because of other relationships that they own.

I want to use NSFetchedResultsController for optimal Core Data and UITableView performance, and I'm struggling to fetch a mix of poems and articles.

What fetch request would give me a mix of poems and articles ?

[image]

Comment: Although subclassing NSManagedObject is routine, I have never heard of  subclassing *that* entity in turn -- at least not in my limited experience. Do you really need to do that? Can't you just have an entity Document, with a property to identify the type of document (say an int that is 1 for article, 2 for poem, 3 for novel, etc.) and a to-many relationship to other documents, representing the bookmarks? Then your fetchRequest predicate could specify which type of document you want per the int property.

Comment: Yes I need a separate Entity because I have a relationship from each of the child entities, for example a note could reference a user, but an article might reference a new agency, not the author... just an example

Comment: Well, here's a post suggesting it can be done, with some tips: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508451/core-data-inheritance-is-it-ok-to-do-this].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something simple like this (which assumes that isBookmarked is a boolean):

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:context];
// This may not be the most elegant way of using a boolean in a predicate, but…

NSNumber *numIsBookmarked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isBookmarked == %@", numIsBookmarked];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity: entityDescription]; 
[request setPredicate: predicate]; 
[request setResultType: NSManagedObjectResultType];

NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *results = [contextMain executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error) 
{
    // deal with the error
}

[request release];
```

After which you would check for which subclass was fetched:

```
for (NSManagedObject *obj in results)
{ 
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Poem class]])
    {
        // do whatever
    }
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Article class]])
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

(Alternatively, if several of the subclassed MOs implement the same method, it might be more efficient to do a `respondsToSelector:` test.)

That doesn’t work?

Comment: not exactly NSFetchedResultsController but that's the way to go. Nothing wrong with creating a fetchRequest with the parent class of a NSManagedObject. Even abstract parents should do.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of Wienke should work, if you just add

```
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];
```

otherwise you will only receive results of the A entity, which should be non as you said it is abstract.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I probably shouldn't have jumped in on this question, but thanks to the more-experienced posters, I now know how to work with abstract MOs. (Sorry, Daniel, for muddying the waters.)

Comment: @Daniel this is definitely the correct answer and should be accepted.